# Function Unable to Fail: Breaks Macros

Tags: vimscript, functions, macro, key-bindings, error

Vim functions do not seem to be able to fail without spitting out 3 unnecessary lines. For example, take this set of functions and maps:

```
" NEXT / PREVIOUS
" ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
" n and N always search for matched pattern forwards and backwards (resp.)
" no more guessing!
function! s:searchNext(forward)
    try
        execute 'normal! '.(a:forward ? 'n' : 'N')
    catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E486/
        echohl ErrorMsg
        echon "\rE486: Pattern not found: ".@/
        echohl None
        " echoerr 'E486: Pattern not found: '.@/
        return
    endtry
    normal! zv
    redraw
    echon (a:forward ? '/' : '?').@/
endfunction
nnoremap n :call <sid>searchNext(v:searchforward ? 1 : 0)<bar>set hlsearch<cr>
nnoremap N :call <sid>searchNext(v:searchforward ? 0 : 1)<bar>set hlsearch<cr>
```

Now try opening a file with this in it:

```
foo
bar keepme 1

foo
bar

foo
bar keepme 2

foo
bar

foo
bar

foo
keepme bar 3

foo
bar

1 | let @a = '' | let @/ = 'keep'.'me' | let @q = 'n"Ad2k'
keepme .. run on previous line: ^y$:<c-r>"<cr>  then press @q at least 5 times

on the 5th time, the macro does not fail on the "n", so the text that would not
be yanked into @a with norm! n IS cut/yanked into @a
```

Follow the instructions.

---

The issue is that `:echon` doesn't fail. So, I tried to `return 0` and `return 1`. This doesn't seem to make the function fail. I tried replacing the 3 lines (`echohl ..`, `echon ..`, `echohl ..`) with `echoerr ..` (the commented out bit), but this takes up three lines with two error messages:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>24_searchNext:
line    7:
E486: Pattern not found: keepme
```

and that--to me--is just unacceptable.

---

So, is there:

1. a way to make a function fail without `:echoerr`

   - it thouroughly annoys me that `:echoerr` throws an error itself .. ridiculous .. there should at least be an `:echoerr` that doesn't throw an error

**or**

2. a way to `:echoerr` without throwing an error or some way to achieve something similar

**or**

3. any other way of making the macro (or another `nmap`) fail when using a map that is bound to a function like this (restriction: you can only make it fail from within this function, itself).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

*...:echoerr without throwing an error or some way to achieve something similar?*

Call it outside of a try block. Per `:h :echoerr` you're seeing this behavior...

> When used inside a try conditional, the message is raised as an error exception

---

*...make a function fail without :echoerr?*

Use `:throw`?

Have you read all of the applicable Vim documentation? Besides the help for individual commands like `:echoerr`, `:throw`, `:try`, `:catch`, etc. there's this whole section: `:h exception-handling`.

Comment: :throw doesn't work. It prints 3 lines still like :echoerr. yes I read them

Comment: I didn't say anything about 3 lines. The question just reads "is there a way to make a function fail without `:echoerr`?.

Comment: I'm not going to accept 3 lines of unnecessary crap every time I press n and pattern not found. That does technically answer one of the bulleted points, but I also made a big stink about not wanting 3 error lines. I can easily fix this one problem https://gitlab.com/dylnmc/vim-config/blob/master/plugin/search.vim#L104 but there should still be a way to make a function fail silently. thanks

Comment: Relax, man. Don't let the "crap" get to you so much. lol. My advice would be to try to tighten up the question. It's kind of a lot of steps you're asking people to go through. You'll probably have better odds of getting additional input if you can distill things down...especially if you can reduce or eliminate the need to enter code in order to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Oh, and you didn't mention my other answer. Did you try to "call echoerr outside a try block"? Finally, what is the link you pasted in? I didn't catch your drift there...a bunch of code...what am I supposed to look at.

Comment: Oh, I guess you're talking about the use of `<silent>`...? Anyways, I'll try to think of alternatives...as long as you chill. :)  (I'm sure that I generated single line errors recently.)

Comment: yep you're right. `echoerr` does not throw an error inside a function (if not in try). this makes the function not be able to terminate the macro, though, since it doesn't fail properly. It's a catch-22. this is why vim needs proper way to **return** errors from a function .. not a hack-job way that is literally implemented in every other programming lang

Comment: actually, I think that the issue comes from the fact that you can't make the **map** fail. Using `n` in a macro when `n` never fails causes it to break macros (infinite loops, etc) when you're expecting the normal `n` behaviour. I was not quite sure what the exact issue was. I fixed it in my vimrc for this one instance, but it doesn't seem possible. thanks